# ggplot facet with two variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, geom-histogram

I have a data frame with the two columns bloodlevel and sex (F & M only), with 14 male and 11 female.

```
   bloodlevel sex
1        14.9   M
2        12.9   M
3        14.7   M
4        14.7   M
5        14.8   M
6        14.7   M
7        13.9   M
8        14.1   M
9        16.1   M
10       16.1   M
11       15.3   M
12       12.8   M
13       14.0   M
14       14.9   M
15       11.2   F
16       14.5   F
17       12.1   F
18       14.8   F
19       15.2   F
20       11.2   F
21       15.0   F
22       13.2   F
23       14.4   F
24       14.7   F
25       13.2   F
```

I am trying to create two histograms that differentiate females' and males' blood levels with facet_wrap.

I have tried

```
ggplot(Physiology, aes(x=sex, y=bloodlevel))+
  geom_histogram(binwidth=5, fill="white", color="black")+
  facet_wrap(~Physiology)+
  xlab("sex")
```

but I’m getting the error

```
Error in `combine_vars()`:
! At least one layer must contain all faceting variables: `Physiology`.
* Plot is missing `Physiology`
* Layer 1 is missing `Physiology`
```

I am trying trying to facet the variable with plot like this:

[image]

Comment: Take `sex` out of `aes()` and add to `facet_wrap()`: `ggplot(Physiology, aes(bloodlevel)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=5, fill="white", color="black") + facet_wrap(~sex)`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying?

```
df <- data.frame(bloodlevel = sample(12:16,25,T),
                 sex=sample(c("M","F"),25,T))
df %>% ggplot(aes(x=bloodlevel))+geom_histogram()+
  facet_wrap(~sex)
```

[image]
Next time please provide a working code sample for us to use (Copying the table you printed doesnt do the trick..)